# Laravel and AWS Lambda function URL - SSE

Tags: php, laravel, aws-lambda, openai-api

I am trying to implement an OpenAI stream event using AWS Lambda on a project built using Laravel.

My current logic has been modified to work on AWS environment according to the custom stream response documentation but no luck.

```
   return response()->stream(function () use ($prompt) {
        if (ob_get_level() > 0) {
            ob_end_flush();
        }
        
        header('Lambda-Runtime-Function-Response-Mode: streaming');
        header('Transfer-Encoding: chunked');
    
        $stream = OpenAI::chat()->createStreamed([
            'model' => 'gpt-3.5-turbo',
            'messages' => $prompt['messages'],
            'presence_penalty' => 0.6,
            'frequency_penalty' => 0
        ]);
    
        foreach ($stream as $response) {
            if (isset($response['choices'][0]['delta']['content'])) {
                $message = $response['choices'][0]['delta']['content'];
                $messageFix = str_replace(["\r\n", "\r", "\n"], "<br/>", $message);
    
                echo dechex(strlen($messageFix)) . "\r\n";
                echo $messageFix . "\r\n";
    
                if (ob_get_level() > 0) {
                    ob_flush();
                    flush();
                }
    
                usleep(5000);
            }
    
            if (connection_aborted()) {
                break;
            }
        }
    
        echo "0\r\n\r\n";
        if (ob_get_level() > 0) {
            ob_flush();
            flush();
        }
    }, 200, [
        'Cache-Control' => 'no-cache',
        'X-Accel-Buffering' => 'no',
        'Content-Type' => 'text/event-stream',
    ]);
```

This previous piece of code worked fine on my local but failed on AWS

```
return response()->stream(function () use ($prompt) {
    $stream = OpenAI::chat()->createStreamed([
        'model' => 'gpt-3.5-turbo',
        'messages' => $prompt['messages'],
        'presence_penalty' => 0.6,
        'frequency_penalty' => 0
    ]);

    $output = "";
    $responsedText = "";

    foreach ($stream as $response){
        if (isset($response['choices'][0]['delta']['content'])){
            $message = $response['choices'][0]['delta']['content'];
            $messageFix = str_replace(["\r\n", "\r", "\n"], "<br/>", $message);
            $output .= $messageFix;
            $responsedText .= $message;
            $string_length = Str::length($messageFix);
            $needChars = 6000-$string_length;
            $random_text = Str::random($needChars);
            echo PHP_EOL;
            echo 'data: ' . $messageFix.'/**'.$random_text."\n\n";
            ob_flush();
            flush();
            usleep(5000);
        }
        if (connection_aborted()) {
            break;
        }
    }
    echo 'data: [DONE]';
    echo "\n\n";
    ob_flush();
    flush();
    usleep(50000);
}, 200, [
    'Cache-Control' => 'no-cache',
    'X-Accel-Buffering' => 'no',
    'Content-Type' => 'text/event-stream',
]);
```

I have define a function URL, set CORS headers as below but no luck as well:

Expose headers
content-type, connection, cache-control
Allow headers
content-type, connection, cache-control, x-custom-header